# Nested for loop with numbers?

Tags: php

How do get this nested loop to echo the numbers:

```
12345678910
11121314151617181920
```

Now I'm only getting:

```
12345678910
12345678910
```

I don't know what I need to do to get it right I've tried to look at some other code here but I haven't found an answer

```php
<?php
    for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++)
    {
        for($j=1; $j<=10; $j++)
        {
            echo "$j"; 
        }
        echo '<br>';
     }
?>
```

Comment: How are you intending to get `11121314151617181920`? Seems to be a fairly random number.

Comment: Oh nevermind...its 11, 12, 13, 14,.....etc. I see now.

Comment: The nested loop runs from 1 to 10, and you echo that number. How do you expect to get "11, 12, 13..." as an output, when you only output numbers from 1 to 10?

Comment: Yes but the same problem when i set the second to 20 then i get two rows that count from 1 - 20 somthing is missing i know.

Comment: `$j + 10` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Use Below Code for your Result

```
    $k = 1;  
    for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++)
    {
        for($j=1; $j<=10; $j++)
        {
            echo $k++; 
        }
        echo '<br>';
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but it shuuld work:

```
<?php
for( $i=0; $i<2; $i++ )
#       ^    ^
{
    for($j=1; $j<=10; $j++)
    {
        echo 10*$i+$j; 
        #    ^^^^^^^^
    }
    echo '<br>';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are telling the code to output the numbers 1 to 10 twice, because you don't manipulate the start and end numbers of the inner looü.

You could do something like this:

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
{
    $startValue = (10*$i)+1;
    for($j=$startValue; $j<$startValue+10; $j++)
    {
        echo "$j"; 
    }
    echo '<br>';
 }
?>
```

which does output the desired result, but may be bad coding practice. I don't work with PHP too often. ;)